Correlative Conjunctions
Consider the two sentences:

The students studied for the test. Their grades were great.

If joined by the correlative conjunction pair (neither, nor), where neither starts the sentence, should we invert the subject and the verb like this?

Neither did the students study for the test nor were their grades great.


Yes, that is correct.

Your negations are grammatically correct, but few people would actually say something like this, it's very cumbersome. "The students didn't study for the test, so their grades weren't great."

Right or wrong, that is an extremely unidiomatic utterance.

@Barmar Why do you assume that this is meant for casual spoken conversations rather than for educated written English, even literary English?  Expectations change in different contexts.

Related and possible duplicates: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, and many more besides.

@tchrist — Spoken or written, that sentence would never be formed naturally.

I would be more likely to say "The students neither studied for the test nor were their grades great. However I suspect it is formally incorrect at certain levels of rigour.
